# How to Store my input value in Variable and store Data Locally

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on a website currently I am working so there is a profile page and edit profile if you edit in edit profile on the button, click it automatically changes content in profile Page but Button is not input type submit it is imported from material UI core and I want it to store locally so it doesn't go on the page refresh

here is Code for my edit profile whos name is Edit.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import "./Edit.css";
import ls from "local-storage";

import { Avatar, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import firebase from "firebase";

function Edit() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [state, setState] = useState("");
  const [zip, setZip] = useState(0);
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  // localStorage.setItem("name", name);
  return (
    <div className="edit">
      <center>
        <h1 className="edit__title">Edit Your Profile</h1>
        <Avatar
          className="edit__pic"
          src={firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL}
        />
      </center>
      <div className="edit__inputs">
        <h1>Full Name</h1>
        <input
          // value={this.state.name}
          // onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="edit__input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Your Full Name"
        />
        <h1>Email</h1>
        <input
          // value={this.state.email}
          // onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="edit__input"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Enter Your Email"
        />
        <h1>Number</h1>
        <input
          // value={this.state.number}
          // onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="edit__input"
          type="number"
          placeholder="Enter Your Number"
        />
        <h1>City</h1>
        <input
          // value={this.state.city}
          // onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="edit__input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Your City"
        />
        <h1>State</h1>
        <input
          // value={this.state.state}
          // onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="edit__input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Your State"
        />
        <h1>Zip Code</h1>
        <input
          // value={this.state.zip}
          // onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="edit__input"
          type="number"
          placeholder="Enter Your Zip Code"
        />
        <h1>Country</h1>
        <input
          // value={this.state.country}
          // onChange={this.handleChange}
          className="edit__input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Your Country"
        />
        <h1>
          <label for="Category">Choose Your Work</label>
          <br />
          <select className="edit__drop" name="Category">
            <option value="singer">singer</option>
            <option value="lyricist">lyricist</option>
            <option value="music director">music director</option>
            <option value="mixing&mastering">mixing & mastering</option>
            <option value="guitarist">guitarist</option>
            <option value="producer">producer</option>
            <option value="event management">event management</option>
            <option value="musician band">musician band</option>
          </select>
          <Button className="edit__add">Add Category</Button>
        </h1>
        <Button className="edit__submit">Save To Profile</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Edit;
```

and here is my code for profile Page whos name is Profile.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Profile.css";
import firebase from "firebase";
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";

function Profile() {
  return (
    <div className="profile">
      <h1 className="profile__title">Profile Page</h1>
      <Avatar
        className="profile__pic"
        src={firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

and I have a file called post.js in which there are title description skills max price and min price and a div in which title description skills max price and min price will be stored just like in freelancer.com and  a Button which is imported from material UI I want that on Button Click it takes that div and shows it on project.js

Code for Post.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Post.css";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Component } from "react";

class Post extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      skills: "",
      maxPrice: "",
      minPrice: "",
    };
  }
  handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  // var titleInput = document.getElementById("projectTitle");
  // var title = "";
  // if(title) {
  //   titleInput.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  //     // When user presses the enter key, then we update triple based on the
  //     // current value of the input
  //     if (event.keyCode === 13) {
  //       title = event.currentTarget.value;
  //       console.log(title);
  //     }
  //   });
  // }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="post">
        <center>
          <h1 className="post__title">Post a Project</h1>
        </center>
        <div className="post__inputs">
          <h1>Project Title</h1>
          {/* <h1>{title}</h1> */}
          <input
            minLength="10"
            maxLength="255"
            id="projectTitle"
            required
            className="post__input"
            placeholder="Enter Your Project Title"
          />
          <h1>Tell us more about your Project</h1>
          <textarea
            className="post__desc"
            minLength="30"
            required
            id="projectDescription"
            placeholder="Enter Your Project Description"
            maxLength="4000"
          ></textarea>
          <h1>Enter Skills Required</h1>
          <input
            required
            className="post__input"
            id="projectSkill"
            placeholder="Enter Skills"
          />
          <h1>What is your estimated budget</h1>
          <div className="post__price">
            <h1>Min-</h1>
            <snap className="post__priceIcon">&#8377;</snap>
            <input
              min="500"
              type="number"
              id="maxPrice"
              max="50000"
              className="post__priceInput post__priceInputRight"
              value="500"
            />
            <h1>Max-</h1>
            <snap className="post__priceIcon">&#8377;</snap>
            <input
              min="500"
              type="number"
              id="minPrice"
              max="50000"
              value="1000"
              className="post__priceInput"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="post__result">{/* <h1>{title}</h1> */}</div>
          <br />
          <Button
            onClick={(e) => this.handleFormSubmit(e)}
            className="post__submit"
          >
            Post Your Project
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Post;
```

and here is my Code for Projects.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Project.css";

function Projects() {
  return <div className="project"></div>;
}

export default Projects;
```

Sorry for asking so much but any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have a lot of code here with no clear question. Please phrase your question as an actual question so we know exactly what you are looking for. Also please consider reducing your code to only that which is relevant to the questions.

Comment: there is i wanna store value of my input in variable and store variable locally so it dont go refresh

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
If, On clicking "Save To Profile" Button you want to store on local storage then you can do this.
```

```
<Button className="edit__submit" onClick={() => {localStorage.setItem("name", name);}}>Save To Profile</Button>
```

Else if you to store it as soon as you type then

```
<input
    // value={this.state.name}
    onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e); localStorage.setItem("name", e.target.value);}}
    className="edit__input"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Enter Your Full Name"
/>
```

Comment: can i acces those value in other page using get items

Comment: If you are talking about this line that I have written. "localStorage.setItem("name", e.target.value);" Then "name" here is called "key" which is a means to store data under particular index. So later if you want to retrieve that same data then you can use localStorage.getItem("name"); Then you will get the same value back according to what you saved.

Comment: Yes, you just need to use this "localStorage.getItem("name");"

Comment: an error is occuring when i write <Button className="edit__submit" onClick=(() => {localStorage.setItem("name", name);})>Save To Profile</Button>

Comment: ./src/Edit.js
  Line 98:50:  Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

   96 |           <Button className="edit__add">Add Category</Button>
   97 |         </h1>
>  98 |         <Button className="edit__submit" onClick=(() => {localStorage.setItem("name", name);})>Save To Profile</Button>
      |                                                  ^
   99 |       </div>
  100 |     </div>
  101 |   );
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: Bro, you have made some syntax error. I guess you have added extra ">" after </h1>. Use Vscode editor to develop react applications and then use "preetier" and "eslint" plugin.

Comment: There should not be major problem as of now. Just check syntax errors.

Comment: <option value="guitarist">guitarist</option>
            <option value="producer">producer</option>
            <option value="event management">event management</option>
            <option value="musician band">musician band</option>
          </select>
          <Button className="edit__add">Add Category</Button>
        </h1>
        <Button
          className="edit__submit"
          // onClick=(() => {localStorage.setItem("name", name);})
        >
          Save To Profile
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Edit;

Comment: I have edited the code I have written. Copy it now.  <Button className="edit__submit" onClick={() => {localStorage.setItem("name", name);}}>Save To Profile</Button>

Comment: not working bro I wrote <h1>{localStorage.getItem("name")}</h1>
nothing showing

Comment: i wrote something in input and pressed that button

Comment: https://whereby.com/sankarboro Come to this link. I will check what you have written.

Comment: hey a problem occured

Comment: plz can you come